# an error on set font-family when i use Text component in React-Native

Tags: react-native

i set font-family to Text component, and it is work good like this：

```
<Text style={styles.iconFont}>
    &#xf11c;
</Text>
```

it will show a custom  font icon

but when i define a variable like this：

```
var icon = '&#xf11c;';
<Text style={styles.iconFont}>
    {icon}
</Text>
```

it will show the same string `'&#xf11c;'`

how is it usually solved?

Comment: This is relevant information: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4818. In brief, you probably need to use HTML parser to parse variables containing HTML.

Alternatively, you can use: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1016

Comment: thanks a lot， i need it